# How to check if a number is between two numbers and use in conditional

Tags: c#, range

Basically, this is what I want to do.. I have two integers, start and end of a range and I want to check if given string contains a number between these two integers. The string can also contain the integer themselves and should be included.

```
int availableRangeBegin = 12;
int availableRangeEnd = 20;

String prefDay = "15"

if (int.Parse(prefday) is any number between range 12 and 20 including 12 and 20 )
{

  // do something
  // will get here in this case because 12 < 15 < 20
}
```

I'm not sure how I can check for a number in a range. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: `x >= 12 && x <= 20`

Answer (score 9):

```
int availableRangeBegin = 12;
int availableRangeEnd = 20;
string prefDay = "20";

int number = int.Parse(prefDay);
if (number >= availableRangeBegin && number <= availableRangeEnd)
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting with C#9.0 we can write

```cs
x is >= 1 and <= 100   // Note that we must write x only once.
                       // "is" introduces a pattern matching expression.
                       // "and" is part of the pattern matching unlike the logical "&&".
                       // With "&&" we would have to write: x is >= 1 && x is <= 100
```

or in your case

```cs
int availableRangeBegin = 12;
int availableRangeEnd = 20;
string prefDay = "20";

int number = int.Parse(prefDay);
if (number is >= availableRangeBegin and <= availableRangeEnd)
{
}
```

Which is closer to what you originally asked

Comment: Only issue I see with this suggestion that should be noted is that the `is` pattern matching requires constants so you can't use this with variables (should your range be dynamic)