# Conditional statements in C# not working as I expected

Tags: c#, if-statement

I'm a beginner in c#, and I am currently practicing conditional statements and others. I wanted to create a simple movie rating code, where the user would enter a value and show the movie's rating.
I'm having a little trouble because I get the wrong rating when I type in a specific number.
A NY help with this code would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int rating;
    string movie;

    Console.Write("Enter the name of the movie: ");
    movie = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.Write("What is your rating: ");
    rating = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    if (rating == 10 || rating >= 8)
        Console.WriteLine("Great movie");
    else if(rating <= 7 || rating >= 5)
        Console.WriteLine("Good movie");
    else if (rating <= 4 || rating >= 1)
        Console.WriteLine("Poor movie");
    else 
       Console.WriteLine("Very Very Poor");


    Console.WriteLine("The movie {0} is of {1} rating", movie, rating);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: try to create your if statemants like this: `if (less1 <= more1 && less2 <= more2)` if u do that u should be able to spot errors. You can read docs about [logical operations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators)

Comment: In my view, we help with homework; but we don't do it.  Consider using `int.TryParse` instead of `Convert.ToInt32`.  That way you can check to make sure that what was entered is actually an integer.  Why do you check that the rating is either equal to 10 or greater than/equal to 8.  10 is always greater than 8, so the `==10` check is superfluous.  In your other checks, you probably want to use `&&` and not `||`.  Looking at the 1st `else if`, a number like 10 is >=5, so you will end up with `Great Movie` immediately followed by `Good Movie`

Comment: Did you step through your code in a debugger?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If statements and && or ||](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33814308/11683)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if a number is between two numbers and use in conditional](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31752764/11683)

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the conditional statements, let's think about what would happen if I were to enter, say, `4` for the rating:

```
if (rating == 10 || rating >= 8)
```

4 is not 10, and it's not >= 8. Moving on...

```
 else if(rating <= 7 || rating >= 5)
```

4 is not >= 5, *but it **IS** <= 7*. Since this is an `||` condition, the result is `true` if either side is true, and that is the case here. I don't think that's what you intended.

You probably want `&&` for these, instead of `||`. Additionally, since we go in order from large to small, using `else if` blocks, you only need to check the *lower bound* of each rating.

As this is beginning work, I'll leave incorporating these suggestions into the original code for the OP.

Comment: Thank you. Now I understand the operators better.

Answer (score 2):

The first conditions in all `if`s are *useless*: `rating == 10 || rating >= 8` - when `rating >= 8` we have no need to check `rating == 10`; `rating <= 7 || rating >= 5` meets every `rating` - all integer numbers **either** less than `7` **or** greater than `5` etc.

Film is

- **Great** if its `rating` is *at least* `8`.
- **Good** if its `rating` is *at least* `5` (and it's not Great).
- **Poor** if its `rating` is *at least* `1` (and it's not Good).
- **Very Very Poor** in other cases.

```
    if (rating >= 8)
        Console.WriteLine("Great movie");
    else if (rating >= 5)
        Console.WriteLine("Good movie");
    else if (rating >= 1)
        Console.WriteLine("Poor movie");
    else 
        Console.WriteLine("Very Very Poor");
```

Comment: @Emmanuella And if you're testing with less than kind of operators `<` you go the other way with your numbers (smallest to largest)

Comment: Thanks, what I intended the code to do worked.